# Custom Format/Modify Cells Column Excel

Tags: excel, format

I am trying to custom format/modify a number in excel and want to restrict the decimal to allow only ones and tens digits THEN a decimal followed by the remainder of the number. For example, the number 32248558 should be displayed as 32.248558, and the next number in sequence would go from 32186449 to 32.186449.

This would need to be done for the entire column of data.

Comment: Wouldn't this be as simple as `=32248558/1000000` or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes but since it's a column how would you format the formula?

Comment: Since each Number is different is there a way to do the whole column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is starting in `A1`, use `TEXT()` to format data. `TEXT()` can format using predefined settings (ex: "general") or heavily customized (ex: "MMM/DD/YYYY H:m:s"). More info can be found here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/01/11/excel-text-function-formula-examples/

`=TEXT(A1/1000000,"0.000000")`

then drag this to the end of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help :)